# Is there a way to disable the systemd DHCP client in 18.04 LTS and switch to the dhclient command line client?

Tags: systemd, dhcp, dhclient

I have a group of automation configs and scripts for Packer, Terraform, and Ansible, that I use for deploying K8S clusters on our in-house VMWare cluster.  All of this is working great now with one small issue: The individual nodes do not release their DHCP leases when they are shut down or rebooted.  Since I'm making and destroying tons of these clusters while testing updates to the deployment scripts, a lot of DHCP leases are getting registered and never released.  Two days ago this finally caused the DHCP pool for the VMs to be exhausted.

I was able to band-aid the situation by just manually deleting the old unused leases for the already destroyed clusters, but I need to convince the VMs to release the leases themselves whenever they shut down.

First I attempted to just release the dhcp leases with a shutdown script in `init.d` that runs `dhclient -r`, but this didn't work because `dhclient` isn't being used to get the lease in the first place -- systemd is responsible for that now by default.  I dug into the systemd config documentation online and found two knobs that are supposed to address this:  `KeepConfiguration=no` and `SendRelease=yes`, but unfortunately these require a newer version of systemd than Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has, and upgrading systemd without upgrading the core OS seems like a dangerous pain in the rear.

I discovered that `dhclient -r` **will** work, if it's `dhclient` that gets the lease initially, so what I'm looking for is a way to either:

1. Convince `dhclient` to release the systemd acquired lease.
2. Disable the systemd DHCP client and switch to `dhclient` entirely.

I have started working on a 20.04 LTS deployment as well, which has the updated systemd, but the change from `d-i` over to subiquity is causing it's own set of frustrating problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if running with root privileges
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Please run this script with sudo or as root."
    exit 1
fi

# Install isc-dhcp-client
apt-get update
apt-get install -y isc-dhcp-client

# Stop and disable systemd-networkd
systemctl stop systemd-networkd
systemctl disable systemd-networkd

# Enable dhclient
systemctl enable dhclient

# Restart networking service
systemctl restart networking

echo "Switched to dhclient as the DHCP client."
```